# Use parameter as column in where in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF(@Search IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @dyColumn sysname ;

        IF(@Filter = 'IsNew')
        BEGIN
            SET @dyColumn = 'IsNew'
        END
        ELSE IF(@Filter = 'IsOnSale')
        BEGIN
            SET @dyColumn = 'IsOnSale'
        END
        ELSE IF(@Filter = 'IsFeatured')
        BEGIN
            SET @dyColumn = 'IsFeatured'
        END

        SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT P.*, C.Id AS CategoryId, C.Name AS CategoryName, C.Logo AS CategoryLogo,
                    CO.Id AS CompanyId, CO.Name AS CompanyName, CO.Logo AS CompanyLogo, COUNT(*) OVER() TotalCount
                    FROM Products P
                    JOIN Categories C ON  P.CategoryId = C.Id
                    JOIN Companies CO ON  P.CompanyId = CO.Id 
                    WHERE P.Name LIKE %'+@Search+'% AND '+@dyColumn+' = true
                    ORDER BY P.Name
                    OFFSET '+CAST(@PageSize AS nvarchar(100))+'*('+CAST(@PageNumber AS nvarchar(100)) +'- 1) ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT '+CAST(@PageSize AS nvarchar(100))+'ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);'

        EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
    END
```

This is the query and its giving this error during run time

> Incorrect syntax near '2'.
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

which means query getting wrong after

```
WHERE P.Name LIKE %'+@Search+'%
```

Comment: what do you get if you select @SQLQuery

Comment: please ignore the +@dyColumn+' = true this is +@dyColumn+' = 1

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '2'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Comment: query causing issue while passing parameter as column

Comment: please show you complete query, including the cursor.

Comment: The `Cast` functions need to be inside the single quotes.

Comment: this is the complete query for this

Comment: where to add cast ?

Comment: Don't add cast... edit it to read, `OFFSET CAST(' + @PageSize + ' AS nvarchar(100))`

Comment: there is no issue with cast and paging

Comment: I mentioned earlier that issue is with
WHERE P.Name LIKE %'+@Search+'% AND '+@dyColumn+' = 1

Comment: adding dynamic column from parameter query does not reading dyColumn as columns

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'IsNew' to data type bit.
THIS error comes if I use simple query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need dynamic sql for this just test for the value of the filter value in combination with the column in your WHERE expression:

```
SELECT
    P.*
    ,C.Id AS CategoryId
    ,C.Name AS CategoryName
    ,C.Logo AS CategoryLogo
    ,CO.Id AS CompanyId
    ,CO.Name AS CompanyName
    ,CO.Logo AS CompanyLogo
    ,COUNT(*) OVER() TotalCount
FROM
    Products P
    JOIN Categories C
    ON  P.CategoryId = C.Id
    JOIN Companies CO
    ON  P.CompanyId = CO.Id 
WHERE
    @Search IS NOT NULL
    AND P.Name LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
    AND ( 
       (@Filter= 'IsNew' AND IsNew = 1)
       OR (@Filter= 'IsOnSale' AND IsOnSale = 1)
       OR (@Filter= 'IsFeatured' AND IsFeatured = 1)
       OR (@Filter NOT IN ('IsNew','IsOnSale','IsFeatured'))
    )
ORDER BY
    P.Name
OFFSET  (@PageSize)*(@PageNumber)- 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT (@PageSize) ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

If you really want to use dynamic SQL instead of Executing it `SELECT @SQLQuery` and then look for the syntax issues by copying to another query window.